# Cannot bind to usercontrol property in Main Window

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls

I have **usercontrol** in which I have datagrid

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public object SelectedItem
    {
        get { return GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty = DataGrid.SelectedItemProperty.AddOwner(typeof(UserControl1));

    }
   <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MySource}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                                SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                         AncestorType=my:UserControl1, 
                                         AncestorLevel=1}}"/>
```

In my **MainWindow**

```
<WpfApplication3:UserControl1 x:Name="myControl" 
                                 Grid.Row="0" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentItem}"  />
```

and in my **MainWindow** **view model**

```
    public object CurrentItem
    {

        get { return currentItem; }
        set
        {      currentItem = value;
               OnPropertyChanged("CurrentItem");
        }
    }
```

I am not able to get the currentItem.

Comment: yes I have already done that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the DataContext of the UserControl to itself, therefore when you set the binding for SelectedItem, you are effectively asking it to look for CurrentItem on the UserControl's DataContext, instead of your main window view model.

Give the Main Window a name and use the binding:

```
{Binding DataContext.CurrentItem, ElementName=windowName}
```